# TestNG reports email after test executions

Tags: testng

I've found various links for sending TestNG reports to be emailed after test executions here are two of the links

https://loganathan1988.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/how-to-email-automated-test-execution-reports-as-an-attachment-using-java-mail-api-in-selenium/comment-page-1/#comment-9
http://www.assertselenium.com/java/emailable-reports-for-selenium-scripts/

I've downloaded mail.jar as well but don't know how to configure all this with my project to send email after test exection

Comment: Above link provides step by step solution to exact question you asked. What _exactly_ you are not able to configure? Explain us your project structure. Are you using Maven?

Comment: I am neither using Maven nor Jenkins structure of the project is I've 4 classes which contains number of test cases and I've configured BeforeMethod for browser & driver initialization and AfterMethod for browser close event for every @Test test case, Now I want to send "Report" for every class when its execution is done. Not I execute each class individually by right clicking on the class and Run As TestNG

Comment: Oh okay. So in this case, you manually have to execute the class which has Mail logic written. If you don't want to run it manually, you will need to use CI servers like Jenkins. Where you can add it as a job. I haven't used it, but you will find articles easily on web.

Comment: Well as mentioned in the links I've downloaded the mail.jar file and activation.jar and created new class in my project SendMail.java do I need  now how to integrate SendMail.java to send email for my testcase class execution and this line from the article where to place this snippet actually

Where to how to use it?


Add the below snippet at the end of the test execution report creation.
[sourcecode language=”java”]
SendMail.execute(ExecutionFileName);[/sourcecode]

Comment: As per my understanding, Line _With this the whole setup of automatic email triggering functionality is integrated with our framework._ says that there is a framework which support this Automated Mail send functionality. As long as I know, using Jenkins is a better option. [This for example](http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/articles-jenkins-email)

Comment: I am not sure exactly which framework author is referring to.

Comment: Okay I will look into it

Comment: one little question not related to this , With @Test annotation can we use both (enabled=true) (groups={“Priority1”}) together

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98346/discussion-between-mk08-and-mubbashir).